# Merge specific sheets from mutiple excel file

Tags: excel, vba

Currently able to copy all sheets from multiple excel files into one excel using the below code. However, I want to copy all data only from specific sheets (name defined) from multiple excel sheets.
need help!

Current Macro Code:

```
Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Path = "E:\Excel_Projects\mergertest\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*missing *")
Do While Filename <> ""
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
 For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 Next Sheet
 Workbooks(Filename).Close
 Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried adding to the code to implement your idea? Where did you run into trouble with it? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach you can try. Copy all sheets to your workbook, then delete the unwanted sheets.

```
Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()

    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path = "E:\Excel_Projects\mergertest\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*missing *")

    Do While Filename <> ""
     Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
     For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
     Next Sheet
     Workbooks(Filename).Close
     Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    
    'One approach is to delete the unwanted sheets, once everything is copied to this workbook.

    Dim UnWantedSheets As New Collection
    UnWantedSheets.Add "Sheet4"  'Add all unwanted sheet names to this collection
    UnWantedSheets.Add "Sheet5"
    UnWantedSheets.Add "Sheet1"

    Dim thissht As Worksheet
    For Each thissht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
         For Each sht In UnWantedSheets
            If LCase(thissht.Name) = LCase(sht) Then
               Application.DisplayAlerts = False
               thissht.Delete
               Application.DisplayAlerts = True
               Exit For
            End If
         Next
    Next
    
End Sub
```